# Adjust Y axis steps

Tags: grafana

I’m pretty sure that I have been able to set Y axis steps in Grafana in the past. Now I just spun up a new version 8 instance and it seems impossible to tweak the Y axis except for min/max. Is this correct or am I just a clown?

So, I have this new Grafana 8 “Time series” showing number of automated builds a given day. This is will always integer numbers in the range of 0 to 5 or something. Problem is that the Y scale in the graph shows fractions and that is really not that relevant and clutters the graph.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the panel settings under `Axes` you can set the `Decimals` to `0`. That should remove the fractions from your displayed graph.

AFAIK there is no possibility to adjust the y-axis steps themselves.

Comment: But then it displays duplicate values for example 0,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4

Comment: My bad, I overlooked you are using the `Time Series` panel while I was checking on my `Graph (old)` panel. It seems there are no duplicates, so if that's an option switch to that panel. AFAIK there is no possibility to adjust the y-axis steps themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue.
On the old Graph, the y-axis gave my graph the value 23, 24 and 25.
After migrating to the new Timeseries, I have got the value's 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24.
The reason, I think, is because the exact value's are in the range of 23.8 and 24.5.
I have set the decimals to 0, after changing it to 1, the issue is solved.
But I don't want to show the decimal on the y-axes, but the whole value.

I find it strange that the new variant doesn't do the same als the old one or has an option to set a y-axis step for an interval of the value's, or is there an other solution I haven't found yet?